# Нужен совет по хранению и обработке данных в ASP.NET CORE

Tags: sql-server, валидация, asp.net-core-mvc

Собственно пишу web-приложение, с большой расчетной частью. В каком формате хранить числовые значения в БД (MS SQL), `float` или `varchar`.

Т.е. меньше заморачиваться с валидацией формы, например используя плагин `autoNumeric` и хранить все в `varchar`, а при использовании данных в контроллере приводить их к типу `double`, или же заморочиться на стороне клиента и хранить данные как положено в формате `float` внутри БД, но делая кастыли для валидации формы.

Подскажите как правильнее поступить в данной ситуации?

Comment: Как минимум не `float`, а `decimal`, и, имхо, конечно же лучше хранить данные в том виде, в каком они будут использоваться. Тем более рано или поздно возникнет какая-нибудь задача типа выбрать максимальное/минимальное нечто или отсортироваться по числовому значению - и что тогда делать с VARCHAR-ми?

Answer (score 0):

Числовые данные правильно хранить в числовом виде. Вообще, старайтесь как можно большую часть проверок вынести на уровень базы данных. Проверка типов - одна из таких проверок. Как минимум, вам не нужно будет беспокоиться о том, чтобы по ошибке не записать в этот столбец строку, которую невозможно потом будет преобразовать в число.

Как максимум, вы сможете безболезненно делать запросы вида "дай мне 10 записей, у которых это поле имеет максимальное значение" и т.д.